# Cloned Snowflake table, why is every column in quotes?

Tags: formatting, clone, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, quotations

I have a table of varchar values, when I copy this table by cloning the entire table has quotation marks around every varchar value.

For example 12/8/2017 becomes "12/8/2017", Finance becomes "Finance".

Wondering A, why did this happen. B is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I haven't seen this happen before. Are you able to provide a small example and put it in your question so that we can reproduce?

Comment: I'd strongly recommend opening a support ticket if this is happening, the ticket should include the fully qualified table names (source and target), the Snowflake URL, the queryID of the clone command, etc...  The more info you give support the more easily they can address the issue.  Let us know how it goes.

Comment: @Benjamin, did you reach out to support?

Answer (score 0):

So I tried to think of a senario where this might happen and I found this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE demo_db.public.employees
 (emp_id number,
 first_name varchar,
 last_name varchar
 );
-- Populate the table with some seed records.
Insert into demo_db.public.employees
values(100,'"John"','"Smith"')
 (200,'Sam','White'),
 (300,'Bob','Jones'),
 (400,'Linda','Carter');

SELECT * FROM demo_db.public.employees;

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE demo_db.public.employees_clone
  CLONE employees;
```

From demo: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/cloning-in-snowflake

You may notice that I had to use ' ' in order for the INSERT statement to accept the data. I did the same INSERT to the cloned table below and received an error.

> INSERT INTO demo_db.public.employees_clone VALUES(500,""'Mike'"",'Jones');

However this worked:

> INSERT INTO demo_db.public.employees_clone VALUES(500,'"Mike"','Jones');

The results of the select * of the clone: [image]

> desc table demo_db.public.employees_clone;

[image]

So the type was still varchar, it just had ' " ' a quote in the string.

Try DESC  to see what happened. I am going to guess that the original table loaded the strings with "" or from where you are reading it is putting it in quotes.  Either way, please share the original data, or a sample of it with support. If you are in the community portal, please see: https://support.snowflake.net/s/article/How-to-Get-Access-to-the-Case-Console-in-the-Lodge-Community